# fastest way to logical OR two vars in C & store in var 1

Tags: c, optimization, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

considering three ways to logical OR two _Bool values A, B and additionally store the result in A again, using the C programming language, what is the fastest?

Way 1: `if (!A) A = B;`

Way 2: `A = A || B;`

Way 3: `A |= B;`

Of course, if you now replace B with a complicated statement, way 3 would be the cleanest and most elegant method.

However, I'd imagine a normal C compiler would calculate the value of B unconditionally in way 3, even when A is true already (meaning that it doesn't have to calculate B); because it's a bitwise operation and not a logical one.

How's way 2 then? Does the compiler realize it doesn't have to compute B in this case?

Way 1 is, of course, the no-risk method; but it's not that elegant either.

Comment: You're fretting about sub-micro-optimizing (nano-optimizing?).  Don't.  There are other bigger hold-ups in your code.  This is unlikely to make a measurable difference to the performance of your program.

Comment: Any decent compiler with optimization enabled should be able to figure out that these are all equivalent and generate the same code.

Comment: and then "fastest" is relative and in the eyes of the beholder, depends on a number of factors which are below the C language level.  Are you having some performance problems?

Comment: Way 3 is not logical OR but bitwise OR.

Comment: @WeatherVane True, but if the types are `_Bool` they're equivalent.

Comment: If B is a complex calculation, don't use Way 3 (`|=`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler why not?

Comment: Right. Logical OR is short-circuiting, bitwise OR has to calculate both.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If the compiler can determine that B has no side effects, it can optimize it away.

Comment: @M.M: Way 3 calculates B unconditionally; the other two do not.  If B is a complex calculation, unconditionally calculating it when it is not actually needed is a bad idea, is it not?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right ... I guess it depends on whether OP wants side-effects of B's calculation to occur

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's incorrect that this is "nano-optimization". This depends on the complexity of B. If B is difficult to compute, and this OR and assign code is practically all that is executed for the whole runtime of the program, like it is in my case, this is not nano-optimization.

Comment: The "optimization" tag is not meant like "how can I optimize my code?", it's more like "how does the compiler optimize this code"; since I already know I can optimize it by not computing B when there's no need to.

I'm not just asking so I can make my 1 OR and assign statement more readable, I was also curious how & under what circumstances a C compiler optimizes these statements. For example, I know for a fact that Lua omits the RHS of the logical or when the LHS was already true, even computing the RHS would have some side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

You could just try it.

```
#include <stdint.h>
_Bool one ( _Bool A, _Bool B )
{
    if(!A) A = B;
    return(A);
}
_Bool two ( _Bool A, _Bool B )
{
   A = A || B;
   return(A);
}
_Bool three ( _Bool A, _Bool B )
{
   A |= B;
   return(A);
}
```

one particular target

```
00000000 <one>:
   0:   2800        cmp r0, #0
   2:   bf08        it  eq
   4:   4608        moveq   r0, r1
   6:   4770        bx  lr

00000008 <two>:
   8:   4308        orrs    r0, r1
   a:   4770        bx  lr

0000000c <three>:
   c:   4308        orrs    r0, r1
   e:   4770        bx  lr
```

The latter two should be faster.  Some compilers may be smarter to figure out a shortcut.  Performance is not directly governed by the high level language in this case but the compiler, settings, linker, target and the code around it, so there is no correct answer based on what you have provided and even with more information it is likely that a high performing answer can be defeated in a benchmark, since benchmarks are generally easy to manipulate.

Comment: In all of these functions the calculation for `B` must be performed. It's not clear from the OP but they might want to short-circuit if `A` is true

Comment: Somewhat surprising that gcc generates different code for `one` even with max optimization. (clang generates same code for all)

Comment: I usually also use clang since you can hit so many targets and compare them, but didnt this time.